# Confusing redstone delay behavior

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to learn about redstone behavior in Minecraft (Bedrock, Windows 10). I just took this video of a test setup, which I slowed down 10x:

In that video, there's a 1-tick delay from the redstone lines at #1 to #2, as expected.

But, the pistons and lamps all activate at the same time, without a delay. I was expecting the delay to apply to the attached components.

*However*, if I put a repeater between the lever and #1 (not shown in video), then the pistons and lamps start having the expected delay...

What is going on here?

Comment: It smells like a bug; I filed it at https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-167483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known bug in bedrock edition.

> If the repeater was activated by another pure redstone component being
> ticked, then the delay will be correct. However, if it was activated
> by a world change (lever, piston modifying a circuit, pressure plates,
> buttons, etc) then the repeater will output a signal 1 tick too fast.

It effects many (all?) versions of the game and judging by some of their comments, it seems they know why it is happening but can't fix it without restructuring a significant portion of the game. I can confirm that does not happen in my java edition of the game.

https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-15793

They list all the effected versions of the game here.

1.17.10, 1.16.200.57 Beta, 1.16.100.58 Beta, 1.16.100.56 Beta, 1.16.100.55 Beta, 1.15.0.8 RTX Beta, 1.16.0.63 Beta, 1.16.0.61 Beta, 1.15.0.53 Beta, 1.15.0.51 Beta, 1.14.30.51 Beta, 1.14.2.51 Beta, 1.14.2.50 Beta, 1.14.0.51 Beta, 1.13.3, 1.14.0.4 Beta, 1.13.1, 1.14.1 Hotfix, 1.14.0.3 Beta, 1.14.0.2 Beta, 1.14.0.1 Beta, 1.13.0.18 Beta, 1.13.0.17 Beta, 1.13.0.16 Beta, 1.13.0.15 Beta, 1.13.0.9 Beta, 1.13.0.6 Beta, 1.12.0.2 Beta, 0.15.0, 0.15.2, 0.15.4, 0.15.10, 0.15.90.8, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17.0.1, 0.16.2, 1.0.0.0, 1.0.0.1, 1.0.0.7, 1.0.0, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4.0, 1.0.4.1, 1.0.4.11, 1.0.5.13, 1.0.6.0, 1.0.5.54, 1.1.0.0, 1.0.6.52, 1.1.0.4, 1.1.0.5, 1.0.7.0, 1.1.0.9, 1.1.0.55, 1.1.1.0, 1.1.1.51, 1.1.2.50, 1.1.3.1, 1.1.5.0, 1.2.0.25, 1.2.0.31, 1.2.3.6, 1.2.5.12, 1.2.6.2, 1.2.5.52, 1.2.6.60, 1.2.9.1, 1.2.10.1, 1.2.10.2, 1.2.15.01, 1.2.16.3, 1.5.0.0, 1.4.0.5, 1.5.0.7, 1.4.2.0, 1.5.0.14, 1.6.0.6, 1.7.0.9 Beta, 1.9.0, 1.10.0.4 Beta, 1.11.0.1 Beta, 1.11.0.3 Beta, 1.11.4, 1.12.1, 1.12.0, 1.13.0, 1.14.1.2 Beta, 1.14.0, 1.14.30 Hotfix, 1.14.60 Hotfix, 1.16.0, 1.16.20, 1.16.50 Hotfix (iOS), 1.16.40 Hotfix, 1.16.100, 1.16.210, 1.16.221 Hotfix, 1.18.2 Hotfix, 1.19.2 Hotfix, 1.19.20, 1.19.21 Hotfix, 1.19.62